# Node.js axios - how to pass an array of strings as query params with same key?

Tags: node.js, axios

I am looping over an array of strings and want to pass these in chunks of 30 into the axios GET request as query params but I dont know how to do it correctly.

const ids = ["1","2", "3", "4", "5"] //up to 10K entries

What I need is 30 ids as a query parameter with the same key on each request like this

axios.get("/endpoint?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4") ecetera. My approach doesnt work and I would welcome some tips on how to approach this correctly.

what I have

```js
 const assets = await getRepository(Asset).find({ collection: collection })
      
      const token_ids = assets.map(a => {
        return a.token_id
      })

      const asset_count = assets.length;

      let config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        headers: this.header,
        params: {
          limit: 50,
          offset: 0,
          side: 1,
          sale_kind: 0,
          order_by: "eth_price",
          order_direction: "asc",
          asset_contract_address: assets[0].asset_contract.address
        }
      }

      while (true) {
        const ids = token_ids.splice(0,30);   //get 30 ids for pagination (max)
        //apply ids to params

        for( let i=0; i< ids.length; i++){
          config.params["id"] = ids[i]; //this wont work cause duplicate keys arent allows
        }
        const response = await axios.get(this.API_BASE_URL + "/orders", config)
        //do something
      }
```

Comment: depends on how your back-end handle it, it could be `config.params["id[]"] = ids[i]`, but considering you are talking about 10K entries, you gonna to exceed the [limit of URL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), please consider to use post or split the query into chunks

Comment: the backend is a third party API that expects the parameters to be like I written in my post. ids=1&ids=2&ids=3

Comment: then the wrong thing with your param is the key `"id"` is overridden, same was my suggestion, so you will need [URLSearchParam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead, or `config.params[\`id[${i}]\`] = ids[i]`

Comment: i know that my solution doesnt work and why. I am looking for a way to archieve what I need to do. I need multiple ids=n query parameters in the url thats get requested

Comment: here is how to use [URLSearchParam with axios](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/get-query-params), `URLSearchParam#append` doesn't override the key, it will append more value with same key

Answer (score 5):

I found this method seems to get the correct url sent.

Adding a `paramsSerializer` method inside of the config will handle all the params sent. Then all you need is the logic to handle the values if they are in array format.

the urlPath `response.request.path` that was displayed using this method was as follows:
`/orders?limit=50&offset=0&side=1&sale_kind=0&order_by=eth_price&order_direction=asc&id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4&id=5`

I am not sure why you had your requests being sent in a while loop but if you need that just add it back in.

```js
const assets = await getRepository(Asset).find({ collection: collection })

const token_ids = assets.map(a => {
    return a.token_id
})

const asset_count = assets.length;

let config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    headers: this.header,
    params: {
        limit: 50,
        offset: 0,
        side: 1,
        sale_kind: 0,
        order_by: "eth_price",
        order_direction: "asc",
        asset_contract_address: assets[0].asset_contract.address
    },
    paramsSerializer: function handleQuery(query) { // this will process params
        // This should query the params properly for you.
        return Object.entries(query).map(([key, value], i) => Array.isArray(value) ? `${key}=${value.join('&' + key + '=')}` : `${key}=${value}`).join('&');
    }
}


// put the ids all into a id array into the config.params object.
config.params.id = token_ids.splice(0, 30);

const response = await axios.get(this.API_BASE_URL + "/orders", config)
```

Comment: Your serializer worked like charm, thanks!